# Borland c++ version 0.7 is it still available?

Tags: c++, c, borland-c++

My cousin is actually asking me if it's still available but I can't find that version, since it's too old, he's complaining about version 5.5 saying that it doesn't recognize his libraries. Is there any link? I doubt but I thought I'll give it a shot. 0.7 is way too old I know

Comment: I think your cousin ought to direct his energy towards writing code that is standards compliant, rather than on finding a very old compiler which will run code that depends on it.

Comment: I might have TC3.0 on disk somewhere... wait, no, I don't.  But I have the manual.

Comment: What is Borland C++ 0.7?  Wikipedia knows of no such thing  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B).  I do still have Turbo C++ 3.0.

Comment: I have the 3.0 manual too! No disc though... Josh 0.7 is the oldest  version ever. That's what I've heard at least.

Comment: His cousin has probably grown up in the last five years without a satisfactory answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools division of Borland was spun out into a separate division called CodeGear. CodeGear was subsequently bought by Embarcadero. On their website they have a Antique Software downloads [section](http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/antiquesoftware). I don't know what you mean by 0.7 as that does not appear to be a valid version, did you mean 7.0? Anyhow if its not at this site you are probably out of luck, though it might be worth emailing David Intersimone the chief evangelist. He might be able to help you, he is a great guy and very approachable.

His email address is his first name, + first initial of his second name "at" embarcadero dot com.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I actually stumbled upon Embarcadero but I thought it was some sort of reseller. I found 1.01 through the link. Hopefully it will help my cousin (he just turned into programming at age 17), last time I used c++ was Visual C++ and I lost track of Borland.

Comment: Your cousin has just started to learn programming and you're helping him by tracking down a C++ compiler for a completely defunct dialect of the language?

Comment: I second Earwicker's comment.  It would be much better to have him start with a more modern compiler ( http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#recommend ).

Comment: FWIW I agree that this old version of C++ is too old for starting any projects with. However I don't know what his cousins use case is, if he has some old code to maintain, needs to add 1 minor feature and is not really generating any revenue from it, then it absolutely makes sense to just try get hold of the old compiler rather than spend time and effort getting his old libraries up to spec.